# Run tests with Spring reading data from a csv file

Tags: file, csv, testing, spring-batch

I'm trying to run a test multiple times, reading the input data needed from a csv file. I want to run the test for each line of the file.

I was going to do it manually, but I discovered Spring Batch. I'm new to spring batch, but I thought the following:

- Create a spring boot application implementing command line runner.
- In the run method, launch a spring batch job
- This job would read the data from the csv file line by line, and for each line would run the @Test method for the data of the current line.

Is this approach ok? Is there a better way to do it? Can you provide any example code about how could it be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, this is not an OK approach because you are trying to add unnecessary complexity to unit tests & also concepts of Job, Job Meta data , in memory database etc come into picture.

Also, Spring batch is not meant to only read file lines but with Spring Batch, writer is mandatory too.

With this approach, control is also reversed. Your tests should be controlling everything and be the driver but with this approach, Spring Batch job becomes test driver.

You should simply read lines of files in `Before` or `BeforeClass` methods and have a master `@Test` method calling a private test method in loop ( for each line & this private method have actual test logic). Your test succeeds if loop succeeds.

You are annotating your test methods with `@Test` because framework should be automatically invoking those methods for you. Invoking it manually defeats that purpose.

Let me know if I misunderstood any of your requirements.

Comment: I think you are right, maybe doing it with Spring Batch is too much complexity. Better do it manually. I've been reading that spring batch is intended for long off-line processes. What I want to do is more or less what you say but the '@Test' method would be the one called for every line of the file. The outer method could be just reading the file line by line and call the '@Test' method for the data of the current line.

Comment: I have updated answer as I don't agree in calling @Test methods from your code.

Comment: Sorry, I think I got confused. My app is perse a test of another one. So maybe I think I don't have to use '@Test', but just call the method of the other app I want to test.